# XY Layout JAVA

Tags: java, layout

is there any sort of XY-Layout to Java?

So I can set a Button at the X and Y cordinate and that it is suppose to be that big etc.... Because this border layout and grid and panel thing is driven me crazy. :)

They are flowing every were and getting strecht up. And to make them small you have to put panel in panel in panel in panel ^^,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When setting the container's layout to null (no LayoutManager), you can set the component's bounds individually with component.setBounds(x,y,w,h).

**Fixed layouts are** in 99% of all cases **bad UI design** (if your labels, for example, don't get their preferred size you run into mayor problems when your application supports multiple languages), so **my advice for you is to rather write a specialized layout manager for your specific needs**.

Writing your custom layout manager is quite easy, all you have to do is to be able to calculate the preferred size for a container with given components and your layout, and to do the layout by setting the (calculated) bounds of your components.
I got rid of the GridBagLayout and started coding my own layouts long ago, and layouting has never been easier.

Here's an example of a custom layout, that layouts pairs of key and value components:

```
public class KeyValueLayout implements LayoutManager {

    public static enum KeyAlignment {
        LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    private KeyAlignment keyAlignment = KeyAlignment.LEFT;

    private int hgap;

    private int vgap;

    public KeyValueLayout () {
        this(KeyAlignment.LEFT);
    }

    public KeyValueLayout (KeyAlignment keyAlignment) {
        this(keyAlignment, 5, 5);
    }

    public KeyValueLayout (int hgap, int vgap) {
        this(KeyAlignment.LEFT, hgap, vgap);
    }

    public KeyValueLayout (KeyAlignment keyAlignment, int hgap, int vgap) {

        this.keyAlignment = keyAlignment != null ? keyAlignment : KeyAlignment.LEFT;
        this.hgap = hgap;
        this.vgap = vgap;
    }

    public void addLayoutComponent (String name, Component comp) {
    }

    public void addLayoutComponent (Component comp, Object constraints) {
    }

    public void removeLayoutComponent (Component comp) {
    }

    public void layoutContainer (Container parent) {
        Rectangle canvas = getLayoutCanvas(parent);
        int ypos = canvas.y;
        int preferredKeyWidth = getPreferredKeyWidth(parent);

        for (Iterator<Component> iter = new ComponentIterator(parent); iter.hasNext();) {
            Component key = (Component) iter.next();
            Component value = iter.hasNext() ? (Component) iter.next() : null;
            int xpos = canvas.x;
            int preferredHeight = Math.max(key.getPreferredSize().height, value != null ? value.getPreferredSize().height : 0);

            if (keyAlignment == KeyAlignment.LEFT)
                key.setBounds(xpos, ypos, key.getPreferredSize().width, key.getPreferredSize().height);
            else
                key.setBounds(xpos + preferredKeyWidth - key.getPreferredSize().width, ypos, key.getPreferredSize().width,
                    key.getPreferredSize().height);

            xpos += preferredKeyWidth + hgap;
            if (value != null)
                value.setBounds(xpos, ypos, canvas.x + canvas.width - xpos, preferredHeight);
            ypos += preferredHeight + vgap;
        }
    }

    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize (Container parent) {
        int preferredKeyWidth = getPreferredKeyWidth(parent);
        int minimumValueWidth = 0;
        int minimumHeight = 0;
        int lines = 0;
        for (Iterator<Component> iter = new ComponentIterator(parent); iter.hasNext();) {
            lines++;
            Component key = (Component) iter.next();
            Component value = iter.hasNext() ? (Component) iter.next() : null;
            minimumHeight += Math.max(key.getPreferredSize().height, value != null ? value.getMinimumSize().height : 0);
            minimumValueWidth = Math.max(minimumValueWidth, value != null ? value.getMinimumSize().width : 0);
        }

        Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
        int minimumWidth = insets.left + preferredKeyWidth + hgap + minimumValueWidth + insets.right;
        minimumHeight += insets.top + insets.bottom;
        if (lines > 0)
            minimumHeight += (lines - 1) * vgap;

        return new Dimension(minimumWidth, minimumHeight);
    }

    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize (Container parent) {
        int preferredKeyWidth = getPreferredKeyWidth(parent);
        int preferredValueWidth = 0;
        int preferredHeight = 0;
        int lines = 0;
        for (Iterator<Component> iter = new ComponentIterator(parent); iter.hasNext();) {
            lines++;
            Component key = (Component) iter.next();
            Component value = iter.hasNext() ? (Component) iter.next() : null;

            preferredHeight += Math.max(key.getPreferredSize().height, value != null ? value.getPreferredSize().height : 0);
            preferredValueWidth = Math.max(preferredValueWidth, value != null ? value.getPreferredSize().width : 0);
        }

        Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
        int preferredWidth = insets.left + preferredKeyWidth + hgap + preferredValueWidth + insets.right;
        preferredHeight += insets.top + insets.bottom;
        if (lines > 0)
            preferredHeight += (lines - 1) * vgap;

        return new Dimension(preferredWidth, preferredHeight);
    }

    public Dimension maximumLayoutSize (Container target) {
        return preferredLayoutSize(target);
    }

    private int getPreferredKeyWidth (Container parent) {
        int preferredWidth = 0;
        for (Iterator<Component> iter = new ComponentIterator(parent); iter.hasNext();) {
            Component key = (Component) iter.next();
            if (iter.hasNext())
                iter.next();

            preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, key.getPreferredSize().width);
        }

        return preferredWidth;
    }

    private Rectangle getLayoutCanvas (Container parent) {
        Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
        int x = insets.left;
        int y = insets.top;

        int width = parent.getSize().width - insets.left - insets.right;
        int height = parent.getSize().height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private class ComponentIterator implements Iterator<Component> {

        private Container container;

        private int index = 0;

        public ComponentIterator (Container container) {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public boolean hasNext () {
            return index < container.getComponentCount();
        }

        public Component next () {
            return container.getComponent(index++);
        }

        public void remove () {
        }
    }
}
```

Just set the layout and add alternatingly labels and value components. It's easy to use, especially compared to GridBagLayout or nested panels with custom layouts.

Comment: Your answer is great but I think it is irrelevant concerning the actual question (about the XYLayout).

Answer (score 3):

The reason components resize is so stuff looks nice whatever size the window is, so Swing discourages straight X-Y position. You might want to have a look at GroupLayout http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html which is designed for GUI builders, and the page mentioned above describes using invisible components to absorb the stretches. eg:`layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);`

SpringLayout might also be useful - see the [visual guide](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

If you really want X and Y then set the layout manager to null, and use setLocation() or setBounds(). I REALLY REALLY wouldn't recommend this, but it does work. Have a read of [this tutorial](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/layout.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this, use

```
setLayout(null);
```

on the component you're putting things into, then use

```
setBounds(x, y, width, height);
```

to set the absolute coordinates of the elements. Example:

```
setLayout(null);
JButton myButton = new JButton("Do Stuff");
add(myButton);
myButton.setBounds(30, 30, 100, 30);
```

However, the resulting GUI will look non-standard, won't be resizable, and if it's of any complexity, will be a pain to maintain.

I know that layouting is frustrating, but in the end you will be better off using a combination of BorderLayouts and FlowLayouts, orGridBagLayout - or an IDE interface builder like Eclipse's or Netbeans'.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your specific question, but as well as agreeing with the other comments, have a look at [MiG Layout](http://miglayout.com/).  I have been equally frustrated with layouts as a Swing newbie, but this has helped a lot.