# Can SpringLayout do all the job

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, springlayout

I would like to ask if `SpringLayout` can do anything like absolute position because I think absolute position have problem when I maximize the frame and what do I have to use if I need to set `JMenu` and `JToolBar` and `JTextField` and `JTable` all in one line in order?

I tried to use `Borderlayout` but it give me very big `JTextField`. I tried `Gridlayout` it give also big `JTextField` I need it big but not as big as it shows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can SpringLayout do all the job

No.  It is neither designed, nor intended to do 'all the job'.

Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or **[combinations of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)<sup>1</sup>,** along with layout padding & borders for [white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556)<sup>2</sup>.

1. [image]
2. [image]

Answer (score 2):

For absolute positioning, [don't use a layout manager at all](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).

However, that's not really recommended. Usually you should use a layout that would scale.

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519918/xy-layout-java) for more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

i found note writing by java says

> Note: This lesson covers writing layout code by hand, which can be
>   challenging. If you are not interested in learning all the details of
>   layout management, you might prefer to use the GroupLayout layout
>   manager combined with a builder tool to lay out your GUI. One such
>   builder tool is the NetBeans IDE. Otherwise, if you want to code by
>   hand and do not want to use GroupLayout, then GridBagLayout is
>   recommended as the next most flexible and powerful layout manager

Comment: I was almost going to mention `GroupLayout` but refrained since the experts tend to feel it is *only* usable with an IDE.  If you are allowed to use an IDE, it might be a good choice.  The advice re. `GridBagLayout` is also pretty true.  I know people that swear by it.  Unfortunately I've never managed to wrap my head around using it properly.

Comment: if you are not so good at GridBagLayout so what you are using for layout

Comment: *"what you are useing for layout"*  That really seems like a silly question given I linked to not one, but **two, *code examples*** that tell you exactly that.  Did you follow the links, or do you expect me to spoon-feed the information to you?  In fact, look at 1st the freaking *picture.*  It includes titled borders that explicitly state the layouts.

Comment: I'm one of those people who swears by GridBagLayout, though I find almost every nontrivial UI ends up needing a combination of layouts. The note you have quoted is correct: If you're going to code by hand, you need to learn GridBagLayout. GridBagLayout is difficult to learn, but I recall one person wisely describing it as "irreducible complexity," which I agree with fully. GridBagLayout is difficult to learn because layout itself is difficult. Everything GridBagLayout addresses is a consideration you cannot ignore if you want your layout to behave properly—especially weight, fill, and anchor.